# Summing the above 7 rows in same column based on a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a series of values that repeat like days of the week doing down in the same column.

```
Monday   : 2
Tuesday  : 5
Wednesday: 6
Thursday : 1
Friday   : 8
Saturday : 12
Sunday   : 4
Monday   : 3
Tuesday  : 17
Etc, Etc, Etc
```

How do I trigger a sum Monday:Sunday's values every Sunday? I'm pretty sure it's done with an SUMIF and an Index call but I've been hitting my head against this problem for about a day now and keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your date column the words, or is it numeric?  Either way, this is pretty straightforward.

Assuming it is numeric:   In C7, enter `=if(weekday(A7)=1,sum(b1:b7),"")`

Assuming it is the word "Sunday":   In C7, enter `=if(A7="Sunday",sum(b1:b7),"")`

Either way, fill Down

---

How it works:

Weekday returns the day of the week.  By default, Sunday is 1, Saturday is 7.
In pseudocode, therefore we are saying:
`If this row is a Sunday, add up the previous 7 values from column b.  Otherwise leave a blank.`

Comment: This is great, thank you. I hate overthinking a problem!